# No console output when using render and jbuilder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm running into this weird problem that causes the console to not show an output after parsing

```
 a= "<%=j render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder',restaurants: @restaurants %>";
json = $.parseJSON("<%= render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder',  restaurants: @restaurants %>");
 console.log(json);


a= "<%=j render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder', restaurants: @restaurants %>";
json = $.parseJSON("<%= render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder', restaurants: @restaurants %>");
console.log("console test");


a= "<%=j render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder', restaurants: @restaurants %>";
json = $.parseJSON("<%= render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder', restaurants: @restaurants %>");
console.log(a);
```

The code snippets above do not render anything in the console, however the code snippets below do give a console output.

```
a= "<%=j render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder', restaurants: @restaurants %>";
console.log(a);


 a= "<%=j render 'api/restaurants/index.json.jbuilder', restaurants: @restaurants %>";
 console.log("console test");
```

It seems like the parsing is stopping the console from outputting anything. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it

Comment: `"<%= rende` and other stuff dont look like json to me. I get 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 ' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/):

> Passing in a malformed JSON string results in a JavaScript exception being thrown.

So, your api does not return a correct json.

Example:

```js
$(function () {
  try {
    var a = $.parseJSON("{test: 1}");
    console.log(a);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('Err: ' + err);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me find the problem. The object did not actually need parsed